# server and db connection once before all test files jest

Tags: node.js, postgresql, jestjs, sequelize.js, hapi.js

I have multiple test files in my project. Each test file has almost similar `beforeAll` and `afterAll` functions which opens server and db connections and terminate them in the `afterAll` function.

I was getting error for server connection which said the port is already in use and I was able to handle that by not specifying a port number in test environment. However I'm unable to solve for db.
The lines below in `.test.js` file are common in all test files. The test itself is a dummy test. I need to have access to `server` in order to call the APIs there.

**.test.js**

```
const db = require('../service/pg');
const createServer = require('../service/server');

let server;
let sequelize;

beforeAll(async () => {
  sequelize = await db.init();
  server = await createServer();
  await server.start();
});

afterAll(async () => {
  await server.stop();
  await sequelize.drop();
  await sequelize.close();
});

describe('testing...', () => {
  test('one + one = 2', async () => {
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/math',  
      
    };
    const res= await server.inject(options);
    expect(1).toEqual(1);   
  });
```

**server.js**

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
    server = Hapi.server({
      port: process.env.PORT || 5000,
      routes: { cors: true },
    });
  }
```

**db.js**

```
const sequelize = require('./sequelize');
await sequelize.sync();
```

**sequelize.js**

```
const user_db = new Sequelize(
  env.dbName,
  env.user,
  env.password,
  {
    host: env.host,
    port: env.port,
    dialect: 'postgres',
    logging: false,
  }
);
.... // add models
```

Ideal solution would be initializing server and DB only once for all test files. Some global setup stuff. But I'm unable to do that.

If I have like 2 test files, one test file works file but the other would give error like:
console.error
*Connection to the database failed: UniqueConstraintError [SequelizeUniqueConstraintError]: Validation error*

Answer (score 0):

**How Jest work and what options does it give you?**

Jest runs tests in parallel using multiple processes.

To run some arbitrary code before all tests, you can create file like `src/jest/globalSetup.js` and export function that needs to be called before all tests globally ([docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration/#globalsetup-string)).

```
...
export default async function () {
  await loadConfig();
  await prepareTestDatabase();
}
```

In package.json or other file with jest config, you need to configure it like this:

```
"jest": {
    ...
    "globalSetup": "./src/jest/globalSetup.js",
    "globalTeardown": "./src/jest/globalTeardown.js",
    ...
```

But any globals set by that function will not be visible to tests. You can however clear the database, or prepare some other external resources.

If you don't like your tests being ran in parallel, use `--runInBand` ([docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--runinband)) to run them sequentially in one process, and prepare database in `beforeAll` ([docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#beforeallfn-timeout)). If all your tests share one database that might be necessary. It is not recommended to use `--runInBand` other than for debugging, but I'd say go ahead and use it if it is more convenient for you.

You can also write you tests in such way that each test suite has its own database, so that there are no collisions and tests can run in parallel. In both cases `beforeAll` is your friend.

**But how to solve you problems?**

We've seen how jest works and what options it offers. But how does it help you?

You've managed to solve problem with port. The reason that it works with random port is that (as said in the text above) multiple processes run at the same time. When you use random ports, each server has its own, and doesn't collide with other server being tested. (I recommend using [supertest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest), it would have solved it for you automatically).

The same problem is with the database. You initialize database in one process, by that time another process calls `sequelize.sync` and clears the database.

So, you can either use `--runInBand`, or you can use different databases, or more precisely, different schemas, with dynamically generated names (but with `_test` suffix, or prefix).

Also, I recommend using `match` option (database safety check) with `sync` so you don't accidentally mess up non-test database, see docs for [v3](https://sequelize.org/v3/docs/models-definition/#database-synchronization), or [v6](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-basics/#database-safety-check).

**Additionally**: I recommend you write function like this:

```
function setupTests() {
  beforeAll(prepareServer)
  beforeAll(prepareDatabase)
}
```

And call it once at the beginning of you test file, or inside test suite (inside `describe`), so that you don't have to repeat your self too much.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of setting up your db in the `beforeAll` do it outside of the `describe` scope once and stop the servers afterwards.

```
const db = require('../service/pg');
const createServer = require('../service/server');

let server;
let sequelize;


(async () => {
  sequelize = await db.init();
  server = await createServer();
  await server.start();
})();

describe('testing...', () => {
  test('one + one = 2', async () => {
    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/math',  
      
    };
    const res= await server.inject(options);
    expect(1).toEqual(1);   
  });
});

(async () => {
  await server.stop();
  await sequelize.drop();
  await sequelize.close();
})();
```

> If I have like 2 test files, one test file works file but the other would give error like: console.error Connection to the database failed: UniqueConstraintError [SequelizeUniqueConstraintError]: Validation error

The reason for this is that jest runs tests in parallel and it could be that your second test starts before the first one has been finished and the `afterAll` has been called.

Comment: You can't use *await* outside of async blocks

Comment: To solve that you could wrap it in an async IIFE https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE